# How to kill a subprocess called using subprocess.call in python?

Tags: python

I am calling a command using

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

The command won't terminate automatically. How to kill it?

Answer (score 6):

Since `subprocess.call` waits for the command to complete, you can't kill it programmatically.  Your only recourse is to kill it manually via an OS specific command like `kill`.

If you want to kill a process programmatically, you'll need to start the process with `subprocess.Popen` and then [`terminate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) it.  An example of this is below:

```
import time, subprocess

t1 = time.time()

p = subprocess.Popen('sleep 1', shell=True)
p.terminate()
p.wait()
t2 = time.time()

print(t2 - t1)
```

This script takes about `.002s` to execute (rather than ~1s if the sleep command wasn't terminated).

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is `subprocess.terminate()`. If, instead of `call` you use `Popen`, it's non blocking and you'll be able to resume execution. Of course, if you call `terminate` right after, it'll terminate before it does anything. 
[Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)