# How do we kill the process spawned by subprocess.call() function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a process with subprocess.call in python

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.call(myProcess,shell=True)
```

I want to kill both the processes i.e the shell and its child process(my process).

With subprocess.call() I only get the return code of the process

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Do you need to do this with ``subprocess.call`` or are other ``subprocess`` functions fine for launching your process? What is your condition for killing the process - time, output, ...?

Comment: Yes It has to be blocking process and the killing condition would be with key board interrupts like Ctrl+C and also sometimes with output

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360420/how-to-kill-a-subprocess-called-using-subprocess-call-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/7509065)

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to move away from `subprocess.call` to do it but it will still achieve the same results. Subprocess call runs the command passed, waits until completion then returns the returncode attribute. In my example I show how to get the returncode upon completion if needed.

Here's an example of how to kill a subprocess, you'll have to intercept the SIGINT (Ctrl+c) signal in order to terminate the subprocess before exiting the main process. It's also possible to get the standard output, standard error, and returncode attribute from the subprocess if needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
import subprocess

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    p.terminate()
    p.wait()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

p = subprocess.Popen('./stdout_stderr', shell=True, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# capture stdout and stderr
out, err = p.communicate()
# print the stdout, stderr, and subprocess return code
print(out)
print(err)
print(p.returncode)
```

Comment: you can use ```sleep 3``` for test

Comment: @AlexB good point, I just put the code I used to test this in a gist https://git.io/JfUuB

Answer (score 4):

You can't when using `subprocess.call`, because it *interrupts* your program while running the subprocess.

How to kill a subprocess created with `subprocess.Popen` is answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Popen`. Here's what `subprocess.call` looks like:

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
"""Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
"""
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    try:
        return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
    except:  # Including KeyboardInterrupt, wait handled that.
        p.kill()
        # We don't call p.wait() again as p.__exit__ does that for us.
        raise
```

`subprocess.call` is made specifically to wait for the process to finish before returning. So, by the time `subprocess.call` finishes, there's nothing to be killed.

If you want to start a subprocess then do other things while it's running, including killing the process, you should use `subprocess.Popen` directly instead.